# Android SDK version 28 does not support play-service-auth:16.0.1

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

I'm trying to include 'play-service-auth:16.0.1' library in my android project but there is no support for android SDK version 28. I'm getting following error :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and
>   libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such
>   incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support
>   libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version
>   lower than your targetSdkVersion). Issue id: GradleCompatible

Following are my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' // <- Error
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I've tried looking for latest version of 'play-services-auth' but 16.0.1 seems to be the latest version. Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this problem?